# Android: How to display suffixText of TextInputLayout by default?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I am using the latest version of the android material design library (1.2.0-alpha05). I have added **app:suffixText="PlaceHolder"** in TextInputLayout. I want **suffixText** to be displayed by default, but currently, it is visible only when TextInputLayout gains focus.
When TextInputLayout loses focus, I can't see suffixText. Here is my code-:

```html
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/textField"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
app:suffixText="PlaceHolder"
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
android:hint="hint">

         <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: When I am launching the Activity, I can't see suffix text of TextInputLayout]

[image: Only after clicking on TextInputEditText, I can see suffix text]

Please let me know, how can I display suffix text by default.

Comment: create custom view for it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use **`app:expandedHintEnabled="false"`** to display the suffix/prefix also when the text field is empty.

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:suffixText="...."
            app:expandedHintEnabled="false"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                .../>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've just created an extension in kotlin:

```
fun TextInputLayout.keepSuffixVisible() {
    val suffixParent = this.suffixTextView.parent as View
    suffixParent.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        if (suffixParent.visibility != View.VISIBLE) {
            suffixParent.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
    this.suffixTextView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        if (this.suffixTextView.visibility != View.VISIBLE) {
            this.suffixTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
    this.suffixTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In code

```
inputLayout.suffixTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
inputLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ->
    inputLayout.suffixTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```